# SSH connection with PuTTY to openSUSE on VMware VM times out

Tags: ssh, putty, vmware-workstation, opensuse

I have installed openSUSE Leap 15.0 on VMware Workstation 15 Player and my attempt to connect with PuTTY times out without any more specific error message.

The host machine runs Windows 10 and for "ipconfig /all" in cmd, I got the following IP address: VMware Network Adapter VMnet8 IPv4 Address: 192.168.50.1 (Preferred) Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

I created a Network Adapter on the VM's guest operating system with static IP address 192.168.50.2 for eth1. openssh has been also installed, as I noticed that on other VM, where the PuTTY could connect, the following process was running: "/usr/sbin/sshd -D" and the VM's network adapter is set to Bridged because of the same reason. I could also ping 192.168.50.2 successfully.

Could you please help me where did I miss something?

Thank you for any repsonses. Any clear explanation is welcome, even if it just theoretically important.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. During the installation, the firewall needs to be disabled, and the SSH enabled. It's an option after entering the credentials of a user.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the reason was different.

I just disabled and re-enabled VMnet8 network adapter (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections). First the IPv4 address of the adapter was 169.254.126.23 and after it became 192.168.247.1 and then the pinging and ssh started working.

IPv4 address of the VM is 192.168.247.147, so the issue was in vmnet8 adapter having a different class network address.